# How I can the cucumber-reporting get working with gradle in intelliJ?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, cucumber

I want some really pretty cucumber reports, like (https://damienfremont.com/2016/05/09/how-to-cucumber-test-report-plugin-2-with-maven-and-java/ the last one with the cucumber reporting).

But I am not able to get it going with gradle...
Can someone pls help me?

Here is my gradle build... I know that it must be false...

```
    plugins {
        id 'java'
        id "com.github.spacialcircumstances.gradle-cucumber-reporting" version "0.1.2"
    }

    group 'Guru99 Bank'
    version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
        testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:2.4.0'
        testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:2.4.0'
        compileOnly group: 'info.cukes', name: 'gherkin', version: '2.12.2'
        implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.5.3'
        testCompile group: 'net.sourceforge.cobertura', name: 'cobertura', version: '2.1.1'
        compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-html', version: '0.2.7'
        compileOnly group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-jvm-deps', version: '1.0.6'
        compile group: 'net.masterthought', name: 'cucumber-reporting', version: '4.3.0'
        testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-core', version: '1.3'
    }

    configurations {
        cucumberRuntime {
            extendsFrom testRuntime
        }
    }

    task cucumber() {
        dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
        doLast {
            javaexec {
                main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
                classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + 
   sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'gradle.cucumber', 
   'src/test/resources/']
        }
    }

    cucumberReports {
        outputDir = file('path/for/generated/html')
        buildId = '0'
        reports = files('out/cucumber-report.json', 'out/test/cucumber- 
   json.json')
       }
   }
```

Comment: What are the results of running this code?

Comment: ``` 
cucumberReports {
        outputDir = file('path/for/generated/html')
        buildId = '0'
        reports = files('out/cucumber-report.json', 'out/test/cucumber- 
   json.json')
       }
```
This part needs to be replaced by you project specific configuration

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Build.gradle -

```
task cucumber(type: JavaExec) {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    systemProperty('envcu', System.properties['envcu'] ?: 'dev')
    main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
    classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
    args = ['--plugin', 'pretty','--plugin','html:CucumberReports','--plugin', 'json:CucumberReports/report.json','--glue', 'CucumberTest', 'src/test/resources']
}

cucumberReports {
    outputDir = file('CucumberReports')
    buildId = '0'
    reports = files('CucumberReports/report.json')
}
```